# UnauthorizedAccessException - EnumerateFiles to parse a network share

Tags: powershell

I try to parse a network share and the script always stop in the middle with a specific folder and throws UnauthorizedAccessException. How to skip this folder and continue the script?

The following code doesn't work (even with GetFiles), if you know the answer please could you provide me a solution in Powershell code and not C# code (as I don't know well C#).

```
  $files = [system.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path, "*",[system.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)

    foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        try
        {
            [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)
        }
        catch [UnauthorizedAccessException]
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Recurse | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.Extension }` give you the same error? If so, did you check permissions on the file/folder throwing the error?

Comment: When using your command, I receive the error "DirUnauthorizedAccessError". But I prefer to use the method EnumerateFiles instead of Get-ChildItem (too slow). Yes, I don't have the access to this folder (and I am not allowed to grant access), that's why I need to skip that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$path = ""
try
{
foreach ($file in ([system.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path, "*",[system.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)))
{
    try
    {
        [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)
    }
    catch [Exception]
    {
    }
}
}
catch [Exception]
{}
```

I believe the problem you were having is in your $files variable is where the files were being Enumerated, thus it was outside of the try statement and gave you the error. This script adds another try and catch outside the foreach to catch exceptions while enumerating within the foreach statement itself. You can do that or just declare the $files variable within the try block. I personally like this better though.

Comment: This is a good answer but it breaks out of the `foreach` it seems when it encounters a file it cannot access which then returns nothing if it hasn't already found anything even though the subsequent folder contains files.